# Not able to switch in webview using appium for android application

Tags: android, appium

I am using below code to print webview of android application but not able to get webview:

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();          
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName); 
}
```

My Application has login feature for gmail using google api and window open in webview. I tried above code to check webview but it only print "NATIVE_APP" on console.

Can anyone suggest me how to get webview so I can switch.

Do need to any configuration at application level?

Thanks,
Sadik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium can switch webview only when it is enable at backend, Here is few links that describe how to enable webview in android application

[Enable Webview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

[approach how to enable click here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/webviews?hl=en)